# VB.NET How to get the text of an Subitem in a Thread?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, listview, delegates

i programming something in vb.net.
It uses Thread's to do some work.
My Problem is now , that i have an Listview with some data in it and some of the Prodcedures need something from this Listview , specially from an subitem.

Now my Question is , how can i get the data from the Listview in a Threadsafe way? 
I tried this

```
Delegate Sub d_getitem(ByVal lst As ListView, ByVal index As Integer, ByVal subitemid As Integer)
Function getitem(ByVal lst As ListView, ByVal index As Integer, ByVal subitemid As Integer)

Return lst.Items(index).SubItems(subitemid).Text
End Function
```

and then called via

```
Dim old = ListView1.Invoke(New d_getitem(AddressOf getitem), ListView1, id, 10)
```

but it always return nothing
can anybody help me:)

**Problem solved**

Just had to change the delegate type to function;)

Comment: Consider adding your own answer and marking it as correct so this questions is showed as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem solved**

Just had to change the delegate type to function;)